# Why $\mathcal{I}_x \longrightarrow I_x$ will NOT be injective?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

Let X be a scheme, $\mathfrak{C}$ be the category of $\mathcal{O}_X$-module sheaves. I want to prove $\mathfrak{C}$ has enough injectives. I found a description like as follows in the book "Algebraic Geometry and Commutative Algebra"(Siegfried Bosch, 2011):

> Fix an $\mathcal{O}_{X, x}$-module $I_x$ for every $x \in X$and
>   construct an $\mathcal{O}_X$-module sheaf $I$ on $X$ by looking at the
>   functor th at on open subsets $U \subset X$ is given by
>   $$\mathcal{I}(U) = \prod_{x\in U}I_x$$ with canonical restriction
>   morphisms. One might think that the stalk $\mathcal{I}_x$ of
>   $\mathcal{I}$ at any point $x \in X$ will coincide with $I_x$. But a
>   careful analysis shows that there is just a canonical map
>   $\mathcal{I}_x \longrightarrow I_x$ and that the latter will not be
>   injective in general.

I can't understand this claim. Why the canonical map $\mathcal{I}_x \longrightarrow I_x $ will not be injective? Do I have some mistake?

Comment: Think about indiscrete $X$.

Comment: If all $I_x$ are equal to $\mathbb{R}$, then $\mathcal{I}$ is the sheaf of all functions $U\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ (not necessarily continuous). Now $\mathcal{I}_x$ is the set of all germs of (discontinuous funtion). But what is the germ of a function ? Clearly there is more in it than just $f(x)$. In other words the canonical map $\mathcal{I}_x\rightarrow I_x$ which associate to every germ $f$ the value $f(x)$ is not injective.